# Timer for a delayed macro on a Logitech G110 keyboard with Lua

Tags: macros, timer, lua, delay

So I've got my first macro capable keyboard (Logitech G110), and would like to utilize it for my gaming. However, my education in programming ended halfway through C programming.
I am looking for help with a very simple script, that sets a timer for a delayed macro, i.e. I press a button, and after N seconds it plays a macro. Here's what I've got:

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)

    if(event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 6) then
        Sleep(360000);
        PlayMacro("Dragon");
    end

    if(event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 5) then
       Sleep(300000);
       PlayMacro("Buff");
    end

    if(event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 12) then
       Sleep(420000);
       PlayMacro(Nashor);
    end

    if(event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 10) then
       Sleep(300000);
       PlayMacro(FlashHeal);
    end

    if(event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 4) then
       Sleep(210000);
       PlayMacro(IgniteExhaust);
    end

end
```

The problem is that it seems to not sleep for the desired amount of time, and seems to be firing at random. If I start more than one timer, the script just completely collapses and randomly fires until I restart my computer.

Comment: I wonder if it can support more than one timer, or was designed for such large delays, does the documentation give details of the maximum wait? sleep is a custom function for the keyboard and not a standard lua function so you might also want to ask on the specialist forums, as there are a couple of posts there suggesting problems with the sleep function accuracy.

Comment: Unfortunately, Lalarm only allows one timer at the time, and I need to be able to have several. I am regretfully unable to understand the instructions of the others, but I guess I shall try and educate myself. Sorry about the bump.

Comment: I can suggest looking into having a C application that watches for the G-key to be pressed, then start a timer function.  The only thing that I am unsure of is that they mention "the application must have focus in order for the polling to work."  This may mean that it does not run if your separate app is running outside of a full-screen game.

I have not coded anything yet, but I will be looking into it later, using C#.

Answer (score 0):

So this won't work at all, since LUA can't have multiple actions going at the same time. It will run through the code line by line. If you press a button, the script will wait N seconds and then run the macro. in these N seconds, however, it is completely unresponsive to any other inputs. If you press more buttons, they will simply be queued after another. So if you press two buttons shortly after another, the script will wait N seconds, then do the macro, then wait N seconds, then do the macro. There is no (easy) way of having what you want in LUA itself, but since you use the Logitech Gaming Software (i presume) you might just want to add a pause into the macros themselves, outside of lua. That does work.